# Nodejs http.get get end page

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made my function
*http://pastebin.com/xaE5Gpks*

The problem starts when sometimes page returns header `302` and is tranfer page, but my function stops at this page. How to make that function continue to a new link which main link returned as transfer link?

Example
`steamcommunity.com/profiles/23123123123123/inventory/json/570/2`
Somtimes this url return user profile to their own id(name) now ID(number)
`steamcommunity.com/id/ownid/inventory/json/570/2`

Comment: And what code are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to follow redirects you can use [request](https://github.com/request/request) library